# Groupby certain months and sum values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like this where no index is set:

`df.head()`

```
    year    month   inch    mm
0   1981    2       0.00    0.000
1   1981    3       4.82    122.428
2   1981    4       6.45    163.830
3   1981    5       5.03    127.762
4   1981    6       1.25    31.750
```

(1) First, I want to select only the years between 1987 and 2017.

(2) Then I want to groupby year for select months: MAM (so 3-5), JJAS (6-9), and OND (10-12) and sum the `mm` column for these months.

The result could look something like this:

```
year   season   mm
1981   MAM      360
1981   JJAS     167
...
```

I'm not sure how to do part 1 but I know that for part 2 I need to convert the `month` column into a date time object.

And then I would define the months of interests by:

```
MAM = df.iloc[df.index.month.isin(np.r_[3:6])]
JJAS = df.iloc[df.index.month.isin(np.r_[6:10])]
OND = df.iloc[df.index.month.isin(np.r_[10:13])]
```

But for now I get the error `AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'month'`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part is pretty simple. Use `pd.Series.between`:

```
df = df[df.year.between(1987, 2017)]
```

If `year` is not sorted, I'd recommend sorting `df` first, use `sort_values(subset='year')` to do that.

For the next part, one solution would involve generating a `dict` mapping and then use `map` to convert `month` to your mapped string, and group on that.

```
mapping = {3 : 'MAM', 4 : 'MAM', 5 : 'MAM', 6 : 'JJAS' ,... } # complete this
r = df.groupby(['year', df.month.map(mapping)]).sum()
```

Comment: Hi @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ. This just about worked. The only thing is it summed the JJAS, MAM, OND values for all the years. So now it looks like this:  `month year month mm    
JJAS 240180 900 4906.636301 
MAM 186186 372 6569.026143
OND 180135 990 4047.652123`
I'd like to have each season summed for each year.

Comment: @JAG2024 Alright, just add an extra group clause, it should work (see edit).

Comment: @JAG2024 Stay classy.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different approach: Use `year` and `month` to build an index, then `groupby()` with a UDF.

Example data:

```
N = 10
years = pd.date_range("1981", "2017", freq="A").year
dates = np.random.choice(years, size=N, replace=True)
months = np.random.choice(range(1,13), size=N, replace=True)
inches = np.random.randint(1,20, size=N)
mm = np.random.randint(1,100, size=N)
data = {"year":dates, "month":months, "inch":inches, "mm":mm}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
   inch  mm  month  year
0    19  31     12  1990
1     8  71      9  1986
2     5  85      2  2009
3    17   8     12  2005
4    10  14     12  1987
5     7  87      2  1982
6     8  59      2  2004
7     8  74      8  2016
8     5   6      6  1993
9     3   7     12  1982
```

Now subset based on year and build the index:

```
mask = df.year.between(1987, 2017)
df.index = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime("{0} {1}".format(x.year, x.month), 
                                             format="%Y %m"), axis=1)
```

Then groupby with `year` and a month-separating function:

```
def month_gb(x):
    if x.month in range(3,6):
        return 'MAM'
    elif x.month in range(6,10):
        return 'JJAS'
    elif x.month in range(10,13):
        return 'OND'

df.loc[mask].groupby(["year", month_gb]).mm.sum()

year      
1987  OND     14
1990  OND     31
1993  JJAS     6
2005  OND      8
2016  JJAS    74
Name: mm, dtype: int64
```

Comment: This is really great too. Thanks @andrew_reece